# Set subfigures on multiple pages to top of page?

Tags: floats, subfloats

I have a figure with multiple images that I want to span multiple pages.
I am using `\Continuedfloat`, however this option places my second figure in the middle of the page and not at the top. I have seen a solution with `\vspace{}`, however this doesn't allow me to write directly under the end of the figure.

Below is an image with an example of the results I am getting thus far.

[image: example]

Is there a way to have 2*6 subfigures in a larger figure, that spans 2 pages and where you can write directly under the figure?

### EDIT

This is the code I have so far with `\setcounter{topnumber}{1}`, but it gives me the same result:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{"Plots Vth shift/D_12-09, batch_1, d_350, T_180, XV_150, I_100-500, C_1_SHIFTVthID".png}
  \caption{Batch:1, die:350-Ta, Transfer, XV:150}
  \label{fig: Batch:1, die:350-Ta, Transfer, XV:150}
\end{subfigure} % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{"Plots Vth shift/D_12-09, batch_1, d_250, T_300, XV_40, I_100-500, C_1, N_after-rest_SHIFTVthID".png}
  \caption{Batch:1, die:250-Ta, Transfer, XV:40  Rested}
  \label{fig: Batch:1, die:250-Ta, Transfer, XV:40  Rested}
\end{subfigure}% <-- added
\end{figure}
\setcounter{topnumber}{1}
\begin{figure}\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{0.55\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{"Plots Vth shift/D_11-09, batch_1, d_250, T_300, XV_150, I_100-500, C_1, N_before-rest_SHIFTVthID".png}
  \caption{Batch:1, die:250-Ta, Transfer, XV:150 Not Rested}
  \label{fig:Batch:1, die:250-Ta, Transfer, XV:150 Not Rested}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.55\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{"Plots Vth shift/D_12-09, batch_3, d_250, T_300, XV_150, I_100-500, C_1_SHIFTVthID".png}
  \caption{Batch:3, die:250-SiTa,Transfer XV:150}
  \label{fig:Batch:3, die:250-SiTa, Transfer XV:150}
\end{subfigure}\\ % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}{0.55\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{"Plots Vth shift/D_12-09, batch_4, d_250, T_300, XV_40, I_100-500, C_1_SHIFTVthID".png}
  \caption{Batch:4, die:250-TaSi, Transfer XV:40}
  \label{fig:Batch:4, die:250-TaSi, Transfer XV:40}
\end{subfigure} % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}{0.55\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{"Plots Vth shift/D_12-09, batch_4, d_250, T_300, XV_150, I_100-500, C_1_SHIFTVthID".png}
  \caption{Batch:4, die:250-TaSi, Transfer XV:150}
  \label{fig:Batch:4, die:250-TaSi, Transfer XV:150}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Transfer curves at different dose rates}
\label{fig: Transfer curves at different dose rates }
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier
```

Comment: Try `\setcounter{topnumber}{1}` to get one top figure per page (or column for twocolumn).  Do NOT use [!].

Comment: @JohnKormylo I have added an edit with how I modified the code to use \setcounter, but it still isn't working, where do I put setcounter for this?

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem was that the second figure was too wide and was converted to a [p] float.  You probably don't need to set topnumber as there is only room for one of these floats per page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{topnumber}{1}
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{Batch:1, die:350-Ta, Transfer, XV:150}
  \label{fig: Batch:1, die:350-Ta, Transfer, XV:150}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{Batch:1, die:250-Ta, Transfer, XV:40  Rested}
  \label{fig: Batch:1, die:250-Ta, Transfer, XV:40  Rested}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\ContinuedFloat
  \centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{Batch:1, die:250-Ta, Transfer, XV:150 Not Rested}
  \label{fig:Batch:1, die:250-Ta, Transfer, XV:150 Not Rested}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{Batch:3, die:250-SiTa,Transfer XV:150}
  \label{fig:Batch:3, die:250-SiTa, Transfer XV:150}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{Batch:4, die:250-TaSi, Transfer XV:40}
  \label{fig:Batch:4, die:250-TaSi, Transfer XV:40}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{Batch:4, die:250-TaSi, Transfer XV:150}
  \label{fig:Batch:4, die:250-TaSi, Transfer XV:150}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Transfer curves at different dose rates}
\label{fig: Transfer curves at different dose rates }
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-10]
\setcounter{topnumber}{2}
\end{document}
```